# Validating node, how connet to polkadot.js

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc, validator, nodes

For running validate nodes, through set up, now i can see my node on the telemetry. but I don't know  how to connect to polkadot.js.

polka wiki says

> "You can generate your Session keys in the client via the apps RPC. If you are doing this, make sure that you have the PolkadotJS-Apps explorer attached to your validator node"

But I don't get it. How do I generate session keys?
I use ssh though google cloud, do I have to do something in ssh? What code is to get the session keys and how my node can attach my poladotjs-app?

I think my main question is
"how can I find custom endpoint(node`s address, wss) from the google cloud (SHH, code, or etc)?"

Answer (score 1):

The polkadot wiki is your friend, if you look on the same page a little [lower](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot#option-2-cli) you see the cli instructions (cli=command line interface=what you need when using ssh).

Using polkadot.js is a lot more difficult because you need to set it up on your server of create a ssl proxy when using the public version.

In short you need to run the following command in a shell on your server: `echo '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"author_rotateKeys","params":[]}' | websocat -n1 -B 99999999 ws://127.0.0.1:9944`

The port (9944) can be different depending in your startup command.

Comment: thanku so much~ u solve my problem~ have good day~!!

Comment: @jayp you should mark this answer as accepted too.